# List of finite groups of Lie type and their BN-pairs

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, groups-of-lie-type

as the title states I am looking for a list of classical groups (or perhaps finite groups of Lie type) and their respective BN-pairs (or isomorphism type of the respective Weyl group).

A quick Google search doesn't yield anything useful.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Take a look at "The Geometry of Classical Groups" by Donald E. Taylor. It's quite readable, and you can find descriptions of the BN-pairs for all classical groups there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book by Bourbaki, Lie groups and Lie algebras, has a full Chapter on Tits systems in Chapter 4-6. You may find google books as a reference. Note Bourbaki is also the canonical reference for anything related to Lie algebra(Serre and Humphrey's books are all based on Bourbaki, to my knowledge).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was rather looking for a nice list (i.e. all the information I need on one page). But at least the book contains all facts even if you have to gather them by hand...

Comment: I suspect Fulton and Harris may have something along the line; but they worked on classical Lie algebra instead, so I do not know. I could not find "the geometry of classical groups" online, so I hope it is there.